# Pandas Dataframe conversion to DynamoDB Table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a dataframe in the below format.

[image]

Am trying to move this to a DynamoDB table in the below format.

| Device Id | SensorType | TimeStamp | Min Max Avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

Struggling with my code below..any help on this...

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(col)
df['SensorValue'] = pd.to_numeric(df['SensorValue'], errors='coerce')
df['CurrentTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CurrentTime'])

minute = pd.Grouper(key='CurrentTime', freq='T')
df = df.groupby(['DeviceId','SensorDataType', minute]).SensorValue.agg(['min','max','mean'])


table1 = dynamodb.Table('bsm_data_table')
with table1.batch_writer() as batch:
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        content = {
            'DeviceId', row['DeviceId'],
            'SensorDataType', row['SensorDataType'],
            'CurrentTime', row['CurrentTime'],
            'min', row['min'],
            'max',row['max'],
            'mean',row['mean']
        }
        batch.put_item(Item=content)
```

Comment: Any help on this will be appreciated.. trying to figure out how to store multiindexed dataframe to dynamodb table

Comment: "Struggling with my code below..any help on this..." Please be more specific, I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code - What works? What doesn't work? What are the error messages?